# Why BinaryReader.ReadDecimal() returns wrong value?

Tags: c#, stream

I stored data type values into a file then consumes it but I get the wrong result. What do I need to do get the right result?

```
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(file.OpenWrite());
        string str = "Lalisa";
        int num = 10;
        decimal dec = 2;
        bw.Write(str);
        bw.Write(num);
        bw.Write(dec);
        bw.Close();

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.OpenRead());
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString()); 
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt16());
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadDecimal());
        br.Close();

        /*
         output:
         Lalisa
         10
         131072
         */
```

Writer output

[image: produced file by the writer]

Note* I'm using FileInfo class for the stream.
The purpose of this is for studying I'm not trying to solve a problem for a project.

Comment: STX is start of message.  You are getting back all nulls.  Are you connecting to a MODEM or SMS?  You do not have a good connection for some reason.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not connecting to anything. I'm just using visual studio editor and run it in the console.

Comment: one issue - you write int32 but read int16

Comment: @vik_78 That's just solved the wrong result! How did it affect the ReadDecimal?

Comment: @RonaldAbellano because you just read 2 bytes in ReadInt16 instead of 4 bytes. And this 2 bytes were read in ReadDecimal

Comment: @RonaldAbellano - once you've read the wrong amount of data from a stream, any *subsequent* reads are going to be misaligned too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the below line

```
Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt16());
```

You are writing a 32 bit integer, and reading only 16 bits back, causing a problem for the subsequent reads.

You should have

```
Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
```

This should fix your issue

**Explanation:**

The bytes are written in Little Endian format, so the 10 int and 2 decimal are written as follows. Square brackets are for marking the start and end of the `int` and the `decimal`

```
[0A 00 00 00] [02 00 00 00...00]
```

But when you read the int as just a 16 bit value, this is how you will group the bits to read

```
[0A 00] [00 00 02 00 00 00...00]
```

As you can notice, the `int` does not suffer in this process and is still read as `0x000A`, but the decimal got shifted by 2 bytes, switching it from `0x02` to `0x020000` which is 131702 in decimal

If the format was big endian, then you would have see the int get the incorrect value of `0x00`

Comment: or change `int num = 10;` to `short num = 10;`

Comment: Thanks that's solved it. But how did affect the next line? It should return a wrong result in the int line, right? Just curious.

Comment: @RonaldAbellano - assume you have 10 apples and 5 people each wanting 2 apples - but the 2nd person takes 4 out of the 10 apples and throws his spare 2 away since he only cares for 2 - so the remaining people will have to deal with what is left.